# Get Controller name and Method in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have to get my controller and method name from route, for example:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I have to get:

```
HomeController@index
```

Also, I have to get name of the action of my route(like POST and GET) automatically from my controller as well.

EDIT:
https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/how-to-get-current-route-name-path-and-action-in-laravel-6

Thanks to this website, now I can get the method and controller from routes, the remaining thing that I still dont found is to how to get the action(ex:POST or GET) from my route

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: If I understand your question your need `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#accessing-the-current-route

Comment: I dont need all route:list, I only need to get the controller, method and action of my current route

Comment: This seems like an x/y problem.  Why do you need to get 'HomeController@index'? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i have to get it for my activitylog in my app, and yes my teacher said that I have to insert it manualy from each of my app controller, for example, home app

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `request()->route()->getActionName();`

Comment: sorry, not working, maybe I should tell you that Im using laravel 6.0